# How do i unlock a volume in Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, files, boot

I am trying to fix a computer but when I try to delete and recopy some files it tells me the volume is locked?

The problem stems from "ntoskrnl.exe is corrupted" error so I'm trying to put a new one on but I am unable to delete the old file.

I am booting with UBCD4Win so there should not be a problem with files in use.  I have also done some research on this and my guess is the computer crashed while doing a SP install and the files I need are locked by a user that no longer exists on the system.

I have tried changing permissions using CACLS but even that says the file is locked.

Anyidea how to unlock this volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to unlock ntoskrnl.exe with [UNLOCKER](http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/).

Actually I would recommend a 'System Recovery Install' (Vista offers that if you try to install it to a computer where Vista is installed already). Should restore the OS, but keep the user data.

btw. That shows that backups should be created before system-updates.

HTH,
flokra